# Magento 2 Css and javascript not loading

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

i migrated magento 2 to a new server, but the problem is that, my css and javascript does not load, i tried:

- **removing the cache**,
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`,
- Opened up app/etc/di.xml find the path
  `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`
  and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the new server using the same environment as previously (PHP version etc)? It's likely that this is a permission issue. Is there anything in your error log files, or any errors in the browser console?

Comment: From which path css and js are loading ? Check if . htaccess file is there in pub/static folder.

Comment: @LiamMcArthur, edited my question.

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV   , the .htacess is there.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source of the home page, it looks like CSS and js files didn't generate or permission issue is there.

To make sure that they are generating

- Take a backup of htaccess file in pub/static please remove static
  folder and run the static content deploy command
- Keep htaccess in pub/static
- Run static content deploy command
- give 777 permission to the pub folder.

  It should resolve the issue.

Comment: The Magento 2 documentation may also be of help http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html